# USMap in R plots only one point regardless of longitude & latitude

Tags: r

I am using a macOS Big Sur

This is the simple code I am using- regardless of the city I only get one point in the map, centered around Nebraska.

```
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)

GeoLocations <- data.frame(City = c("Atlanta","Seattle"),
                           Latitude = c(33.45,47.37),
                           Longitude = c(-84.23,-122.2))
plot_usmap(regions ="state") +
  geom_point(data = GeoLocations, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))
```

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`usmap` package requires an other coordinate system that is different from yours (it is already explained here : [Add points to usmap with ggplot in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52911837/add-points-to-usmap-with-ggplot-in-r))

To solve this you need :

```
GeoLocations <- data.frame(Longitude = c(-84.23,-122.2),
                           Latitude = c(33.45,47.37)) #keeping only Longitude and Latitude columns
GeoLocations <- usmap_transform(GeoLocations) #transform coordinates
plot_usmap(regions ="state") + geom_point(data = GeoLocations, aes(x = Longitude.1, y = Latitude.1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To expand @BastienDucreux's answer, you can also help ggplot to recognize the coordinate reference system and then use the [ggspatial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggspatial/index.html) package to plot the points.

```
library(ggspatial)

plot_usmap(regions ="state") +
  coord_sf(crs = usmap::usmap_crs()) +
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_point(data = GeoLocations,
                                aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), crs = 4326)
```

[image]